# “PTY allocation request failed on channel 0 stdin: is not a tty” when SSH'ing into a Debian server

Tags: debian, ssh, mount, fstab

My hosting space (Debian Wheezy) serves two websites (one WordPress and one Rails). Today I saw both were down and I rebooted the server. The Rails site works again and the WordPress one now says that it has an error connecting to the database. Then after the reboot (from SSH as well) I SSH'ed into the server I got the following message:

```
PTY allocation request failed on channel 0
stdin: is not a tty
```

When I run with `-v` flag I get output with nothing strange  I think (just checking the public and private key). See [this](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/4ab7e01a5d1cb954f044) gist.

When I SSH as follows `ssh user@host "/bin/bash -i"` I *can* login into the remote shell.

I read in [another answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/351162/ssh-fails-pty-allocation-request-failed-on-channel-0) (which also provided also the tip with appending "bin/bash -i" and that helped) that I should manually remove and re-add the `/dev/pt*` files. The one who asked the question said that unmounting `/dev/pts` and remounting it worked. Unfortunately I get the error:

```
Can't find /dev/pts in /etc/fstab or /etc/mtab
```

My `/etc/fstab` files looks like this:

```
#UNCONFIGURED FSTAB FOR BASE SYSTEM
```

Does anyone have any idea what is going on and how I can solve this?

Output of `tty; ls -l /proc/self/fd` locally:

```
/dev/pts/2
total 0
lrwx------ 1 erwin erwin 64 Sep 13 19:01 0 -> /dev/pts/2
lrwx------ 1 erwin erwin 64 Sep 13 19:01 1 -> /dev/pts/2
lrwx------ 1 erwin erwin 64 Sep 13 19:01 2 -> /dev/pts/2
lr-x------ 1 erwin erwin 64 Sep 13 19:01 3 -> /proc/4389/fd
```

Output of `ls -la /dev/ptmx /dev/pts` on remote machine:

```
crw-rw-rw- 1 root tty  5, 2 Sep 11 00:19 /dev/ptmx

/dev/pts:
total 8
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Mar 10  2013 .
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 Sep 11 00:35 ..
```

Login via `ssh root@host "/bin/bash -i"` at 18:10 and looked in `/var/log`. Besides a cronjob I saw one file that was edited:

```
-rw-r----- 1 root        adm       614306 Sep 15 18:10 auth.log
```

and syslog (via cronjob). Syslog was a coincidence since something happened every 30 minutes which relates to PHP.

Then I copied the file via `scp` to local.

auth.log:

```
Sep 15 18:10:23 vz1223 sshd[23681]: Accepted publickey for root from [localIp] port 39126 ssh2
Sep 15 18:10:23 vz1223 sshd[23681]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Sep 15 18:12:14 vz1223 sshd[23681]: Received disconnect from [localIp]: 11: disconnected by user
Sep 15 18:12:14 vz1223 sshd[23681]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session closed for user root
Sep 15 18:12:29 vz1223 sshd[23700]: Accepted publickey for root from [localIp] port 39160 ssh2
Sep 15 18:12:29 vz1223 sshd[23700]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Sep 15 18:12:29 vz1223 sshd[23700]: Received disconnect from [localIP]: 11: disconnected by user
Sep 15 18:12:29 vz1223 sshd[23700]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session closed for user root
Sep 15 18:12:47 vz1223 sshd[23709]: Accepted publickey for root from [localIp] port 39163 ssh2
Sep 15 18:12:47 vz1223 sshd[23709]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
```

As said, according to [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/351162/ssh-fails-pty-allocation-request-failed-on-channel-0#351222) answer to a similar question I should `umount` and `mount` my `/dev/pts` by running `mount -t devpts -o OPTIONS devpts /dev/pts`.

When I run `mount` I do not see `/dev/pts`/ And when I run `mount /dev/pts/` I get: `can't find /dev/pts in /etc/fstab or /etc/mtab`. The output of `mount` is the following:

```
/home/vz/private/1223 on / type simfs (rw,relatime)<br>
proc on /proc type proc (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)<br>
sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)<br>
tmpfs on /run type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime,size=6556k,mode=755)<br>
tmpfs on /run/lock type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,size=5120k)<br>
tmpfs on /run/shm type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,size=39320k)<br>
```

Perhaps I should get `/dev/pts` to mount again?

More logging with running `ssh -vvv user@host` gives [this](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/fe3179fcdb46b91e262e).

result of `namei -lx /dev/pts` on host:

```
f: /dev/pts
Drwxr-xr-x root root /
drwxr-xr-x root root dev
drwxr-xr-x root root pts
```

*/edit 6/ I rebooted the server once again from SSH with the "`/bin/bash -i`" appended via the `reboot` command and now the terminal is back to normal... I have no idea what went wrong nor what solved it, but it works again.

Comment: Are you running these SSH sessions from a terminal? Post the output of `tty; ls -l /proc/self/fd` on the local machine, and of `ls -la /dev/ptmx /dev/pts` on the remote machine. By the way, it's normal that `/dev/pts` wouldn't be mentioned in `/etc/fstab`, most distributions hard-code it in startup scripts.

Comment: Does anything appear in a log file? Check all files in `/var/log` that got modified at the time of the login attempt and post all messages generated at that time (replace host names by placeholders for privacy).

Comment: @Gilles Nothing appears in `/var/log` except a change to `auth.log`. I added this.

Comment: You can run `ssh` with more than one `-v` for increased logging: `ssh -vvv ...`

Comment: @garethTheRed Added the output.

Comment: Hmmm. I didn't say it would help though :-(  Can you paste the output of `namei -lx /dev/pts*` please.

Comment: @garethTheRed Haha np thank you. I pasted the result into the question.

Comment: Okay... I rebooted the server once again and now the terminal works again.

Comment: From the last edit, your `dev` filesystem hadn't mounted for some reason.

Comment: Are you chrooting?

Comment: On a running Debian system the `/dev` directory is a `tmpfs` mounted filesystem. Within that mount, `/dev/pts` is a `devpts` mounted filesystem. The `namei -lx <full path>` command displays `d` for directories and `D` for mount points for as the first character of each line.  Your results showed `/` as a mount point (`D`) and the other two as mere sub-directories (`d`).  That suggests that they hadn't been mounted as `/dev` and `/dev/pts`. As it's working now, running that command again should show `D`s.

Comment: I presume you've tried `ssh -t ...` ("force pseudo-tty allocation") but it hasn't been noted anywhere.  If that doesn't work, try `ssh -tt ...` ("force tty allocation even if ssh has no local tty").

Answer (score 1):

So, `/dev/pts` is a virtual filesystem in the kernel for the `p`seudo `t`erminal `s`(omething; not sure what the s stands for). It is a virtual kernel-only filesystem that exports some data from the kernel, very much like `sysfs` (/sys) and `procfs` (/proc) do as well. The filesystem should be mounted with a type `devpts`, on `/dev/pts`.

This is a special filesystem that doesn't usually appear in `/etc/fstab`, but it needs to be mounted. Usually distributions have init scripts or similar to do the mounts needed; but occasionally this may fail, and then you get issues like that.

On systemd-based systems, this problem should not occur anymore; systemd takes care of ensuring that the `devpts` filesystem is mounted.

If you use a different init system, then the fix may depend on the distribution you use. On Debian with `sysvinit`, the `devpts` filesystem is mounted by the `mountdevsubfs.sh` init script. If you run into this problem ever again, you can do one of two things:

- Run `/etc/init.d/mountdevsubfs.sh restart`
- Bypass the init script and manually run `mount -t devpts devpts /dev/pts`